# Is it practical to use Git with CS school work?

Tags: git

I'm taking two 200 level CS classes (C++ and Assembly) this semester and would like to learn git. Is it practical to use it for my class work even though they might be small assignments?

Comment: I don't consider it practical to do homework without Git, for any subject...

Comment: I wrote an article on how we use Git and Github for our rails dev bootcamp (with lots of exercises): http://sebastien.saunier.me/blog/2014/04/21/practical-example-of-using-git-in-a-school.html

Answer (score 4):

Yes, yes it is practical. I use it in this way.

Git is rather lightweight and shouldn't be too much trouble to learn alongside your courses. You might want to consider using a service such as [BitBucket](https://bitbucket.org/) to host your code, though you don't have to.

Also, keep a link to [gitref](http://gitref.org/) handy.

Comment: +1 on bitbucket, especially because you can use git or mercurial repos now

Answer (score 2):

I would highly recommend learning how to use it with small code bases first. This will seriously help you out later on. The situation you want to avoid is being presented with a massive set of code and at the same time learning how the basics work (forking and committing etc)!

Additionally, using git/mercurial for small projects is very convenient. I know people who use it to store versions of their resume, notes, and, more relevantly, cs homework.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, learn Git while you are learning your courses.  There are two main benefits:

1. It provides you with protection against losing your work - if you commit often enough.
2. It provides you with practice at using a VCS - that it is a DVCS too is not critical, but is also good experience.

The one thing you'll have to work on slightly artificially is using branches.  Maybe you should treat the main branch as where you store your final solutions for each assignment, while you develop each one on its own development branch.  Unless your assignments are designed to build on prior work, though, you won't necessarily get all that much experience of more complex merges.  But I don't do development without using a VCS for retaining the information.

(As to 'commit often enough' - any time the code compiles and has made progress towards your destination, think about a commit so that if the next changes or additions cause trouble, you can go back to a known 'good' state.  That can be very valuable.  As you get more experienced, you may find that you wait until you've made more changes between commits, but keeping commits frequent is still important.)